# SQL query CTE or while for case to split lines with correct quantity

Tags: sql, while-loop, common-table-expression

We have an issue that we don’t know how to solve, help is very welcome or an example how to fix such cases.

This concerns purchase needs that have been combined into one purchase line. On receipt, the lines can be split due to multiple batch numbers. Below we have described the case. should there be a recursive solution (cte) for this or a while?

Needs that are combined into one purchase line

| purchase_need_id | quantity | item_id | warehouse_id | purchase_order_id | purchase_order_line_item_id | date_needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5303 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 07/08/2021 |
| 5304 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 23/07/2021 |
| 5344 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 09/07/2021 |
| 5345 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 23/08/2021 |

The goods receipt

| goods_receipt_id | goods_receipt_line_item_id | purchase_order_id | purchase_order_line_item_id | item_id | quantity | lot_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 84 | 240 | 1435 | 114159 | 120.00 | 654654 |
| 25 | 85 | 240 | 1435 | 114159 | 180.00 | 654445 |

a result like below is required, sorted bij date_needed

| purchase_need_id | quantity | item_id | warehouse_id | purchase_order_id | purchase_order_line_item_id | date_needed | goods_reciept_id | goods_receipt_line_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5344 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 09/07/2021 | 25 | 84 |
| 5304 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 23/07/2021 | 25 | 85 |
| 5303 | 60.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 07/08/2021 | 25 | 85 |
| 5303 | 60.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 07/08/2021 |  |  |
| 5345 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 23/08/2021 |  |  |

The purchase needs updated / inserted ordered by need_date

| goods_receipt_id | goods_receipt_line_item_id | purchase_order_id | purchase_order_line_item_id | item_id | quantity | lot_id | linked | purchase_need_id | quantity | item_id | warehouse_id | purchase_order_id | purchase_order_line_item_id | date_needed | goods_reciept_id | goods_receipt_line_item_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 84 | 240 | 1435 | 114159 | 120.00 | 654654 | --> | 5344 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 09/07/2021 | 25 | 84 |
| 25 | 85 | 240 | 1435 | 114159 | 180.00 | 654445 | --> | 5304 | 120.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 23/07/2021 | 25 | 85 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | --> | 5303 | 60.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 07/08/2021 | 25 | 85 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | remaining quantity | 5303 | 60.00 | 114159 | 8 | 240 | 1435 | 07/08/2021 |  |  |

Comment: Could you explain business logic for your required result? And couldn't find `batch numbers` in your data: `This concerns purchase needs that have been combined into one purchase line. On receipt, the lines can be split due to multiple batch numbers`

Comment: in this case lot_id is the batch number. A receipt line is splitted and the needs must be linked with the correct quantity and possibly new lines must be created with the remaining quantity that has not yet been received.  
one receipt line can be linked to multiple needs where the last line may need to be split with the remaining quantity.